# how can I set my document id as user uid in cloud fire store?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  //final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

//Here I have set my own controller name
  TextEditingController sampledata1 = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController sampledata2 = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget> [
              TextFormField(
                controller: sampledata1,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Simple data 1"
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
              TextFormField(
                controller: sampledata2,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Simple data 2"
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () async {
//Here I am trying to add document on firestore with users uid but could not get any solution
                  final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
                 Map <String, dynamic> data = {"field1": sampledata1.text, "field2": sampledata2.text};
                  //FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("UserData").add(data);
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
                color: Colors.red[600],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `add(...)` Firestore auto-generates an ID for the new document for you.

If you want to control the ID yourself, use `doc(uid).set(...)`:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("UserData").doc(uid).set(data);
```

Comment: Thank u for that I got it but now nothing is displaying on my firestore.. I think I have pass my uid wrong.... any idea on idea on how to pass it correctly...I'm using Google account to log in to my system

Comment: I focused my answer on how to use a value you determine as the document ID. If your code for looking up the UID is not working, you should be able to confirm that in the debugger by checking the value of `uid` after this line executes `final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();`.

Answer (score 1):

Im updating your onPress method, Just replace it and it will work

```
             FlatButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final currentUid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
                 Map <String, dynamic> data = {"field1": sampledata1.text, "field2": sampledata2.text};
                  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("UserData").doc(currentUid).add(data);
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
                color: Colors.red[600],
              )
```

If it works then please approve my answer.