# send data to firebase with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to send the data to firebase in my project which I was able to , yet I want the data to override the variable. The one I am using is adding at all the time

```
 setState(() {
      velocity = newVelocity;

      if (velocity > highestVelocity) {
        highestVelocity = velocity;
      }
    });
      future= new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
     _firestore.collection('collectionName').add({
                      'velocity' : velocity
                      
         }); 
}
```

I think there is update function to override the var. Can I someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

To update an existing document, you must know the ID of that document. Once you do, you can update it with:

```
_firestore.collection('collectionName').doc("theIdOfYourDocument").set({
  'velocity' : velocity                  
});
```

Also see: [how can I set my document id as user uid in cloud fire store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66198667/how-can-i-set-my-document-id-as-user-uid-in-cloud-fire-store/66199351#66199351)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I got to work, but Ihad to change set to setdata